# Planar Curve - differential equation condition

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry

This is an exercise in a book.

[image: pic1]

So we need to find the most general function $g$ such that this curve      from $\mathbb{R}^3$

$f(t) = (a\cos(t), a\sin(t), g(t))$

lies in a plane.

It's not mentioned but there, but I guess we can assume that

1. $g$ is e.g. 3 times differentiable
2. $a \ne 0$

With these assumptions in mind, I know that for the curve to be planar we must have that the torsion $\tau(t) = 0$ for any $t$.

The formula for the torsion is well-known. From it I got that this requirement translates to $g'(t) + g'''(t) = 0$.

I don't know differential equations so I cannot continue further from here.

But the book gives this answer:

$g(t) = b\cos(t) + c\sin(t) + d$

I could easily verify that this function satisfies the equation I got. OK... So my question is: does that mean that **the only solution** to the differential equation I got is the function given in the book's answer? Where can I loop up some basic theory about this differential equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting $g'(t)=u(t)$ your equation becomes:
$$
u''(t)=-u(t)
$$
whose general solution is
$$
u(t)=A\cos t+B\sin t,
$$
with $A$ and $B$ arbitrary constants. Then integrate $u(t)$ to get $g(t)$.

EDIT.

The same result can be reached without calculus. The projection of the curve on the $xy$ plane is a circle. The curve could lie on any plane not perpendicular to $xy$ plane, whose general equation can be written as:
$$
z=bx+cy+d.
$$
Subsitute here $x=a\cos t$ and $y=a\sin t$ to get $z=g(t)$.

Comment: Thanks. So what you're saying is that this is a pretty basic fact, right? I mean, if one studies ODEs this will occur pretty early in the course so to speak.

Comment: Yes, this is a very simple second order differential equation, see for instance: https://www.ncl.ac.uk/webtemplate/ask-assets/external/maths-resources/core-mathematics/calculus/homogeneous-second-order-differential-equations.html

Comment: OK, I see. Thank you.